# Code not working in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5, osx-yosemite

I have used Xcode 5, my appcode is working fine in 10.8 OS but when i am updating it with 10.10, code shows an error i.e.

```
Command/Applications/Xcode2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Comment: welcome to the beta-testers' world.

Comment: Restart ? Reinstall Xcode .... it's likely a beta issue with Yosemite

Comment: restart many times !! don't want to reinstall

Comment: @RinjuJain if you don't want  to reinstall then you will just have to live with the problem.

Comment: i had reinstall xcode5 but having same problem ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall the Xcode to rectify this error because you update to OS X Yosemite beta, some files are in conflict now.